# Locust/Python: Splitting a tasks array with if conditions in a SequentialTaskSet

Tags: python, locust

I'm new to Locust, and Python in general. I've been using JMeter for several years, and I'm trying to implement similar logic to what I've used there for handling failures in login.

I want to run a simple scenario: Login, Enter a folder, Logout

Where I'm having trouble is implementing this logic:

If any login call fails, I don't want to attempt the folder enter (avoid a cascading failure after login), but I still want to run the logout to ensure there is no active session.

My current SequentialTaskSet reads like this, which works for executing the child tasksets:

```
class folder_enter_scalability_taskset(SequentialTaskSet):

    def on_start(self):
        self.tm = TransactionManager()

    @task
    def seedata_config(self):
        seeddata = next(seeddata_reader)
        self.client.username = seeddata['username']
        self.client.password = seeddata['password']

    tasks = [login_taskset, folder_enter_taskset, logout_taskset]
```

Is there a way to split up the tasks array into multiple steps within the same SequentialTaskSet?

1. Always Login
2. if login passed, enter folder
3. Always Logout

Comment: Is there any reason why creating one task with the login, folder_enter, and logout functions wouldn't work? You could then wrap your login and folder_enter in a try-finally with your finally block being logout

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I do understand how that would work. But these are kept as separate scripts because we want each transaction to be reusable in different scenarios. 

For example, this scenario has the transactions of Login, Folder Enter, Logout.

Another scenario might be Login, Create Folder, Delete Folder, Logout.

So we want a script with only login, which can be called by any scenario, same for logout, and so on, so that the same calls don't have to be maintained across multiple scripts

Comment: You can still keep them as separate scripts but wrap them into one task. I’m assuming this is for testing

Comment: I may have misunderstood the initial suggestion then. As long as the reusable transactions are kept as separate scripts, I'm fine with writing this in any way that will work for the given logic. Do you have an example code of how they would be wrapped into one task? Would this involve calling the child tasksets without an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to phil in the comments for pointing me in the right direction, I now have a working code with try-finally and if-else instead of a tasks array. Hope this can help someone else:

```
class folder_enter_scalability_taskset(SequentialTaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        self.tm = TransactionManager()

    @task
    def seedata_config(self):
        seeddata = next(seeddata_reader)
        self.client.username = seeddata['username']
        self.client.password = seeddata['password']
        self.client.userrole = seeddata['userrole']

    @task
    def folder_enter_scalability(self):
        try:
            login_taskset.login(self)
            if self.client.loginFail is False:
                folder_enter_taskset.folder_enter(self)
            else:
                logging.error("Login failed, skipping to logout")
        finally:
            logout_taskset.logout(self)
```

I wasn't having luck with getting it to skip folder enter if I placed it in a try-else-finally condition, so I went with adding this self.client.loginFail in the login taskset to support if-else within try.

It's initiated as 'False', and flipped to 'True' in case of failure in the taskset.